# vb.net creating data table?

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I'm using vb.net / winforms.
How can I convert 10 lines with three columns into a DataSet/DataTable?

Lines are something like this:

```
Item-1, $100, 44

Item-2, $42, 3

etc
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
Dim Table1 As DataTable
Table1 = New DataTable("TableName")

Dim column1 As DataColumn = New DataColumn("Column1")
column1.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")

Dim column2 As DataColumn = New DataColumn("Column2")
column2.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32") 
Dim column3 As DataColumn = New DataColumn("Column2")
column3.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32")

Table1.Columns.Add(column1)
Table1.Columns.Add(column2)
Table1.Columns.Add(column3)


Dim Row1 As DataRow
Row1 = Table1.NewRow()

Row1.Items("Column1") = "Item1"
Row1.Items("Column2") = 44
Row1.Items("Column3") = 99

Table1.Rows.Add(Row1)

' Repeat for other rows
```

Comment: Thanks. Need to update column3 definition: `Dim column3 As DataColumn = New DataColumn("Column3")`

Comment: I had to use `Row1.Item("Column1") = "Item1"` instead of `Items()` for some reason, but I was able to get it to work.

Answer (score 24):

I know this post is old, but I believe this can be solved in fewer lines of code.

```
' Declare DataTable
Dim Table1 As new DataTable()
' Define columns
Table1.Columns.Add("Column1", GetType(System.String))
Table1.Columns.Add("Column2", GetType(System.Int32))
Table1.Columns.Add("Column3", GetType(System.Int32))
' Add a row of data
Table1.Rows.Add("Item1", 44, 99)
Table1.Rows.Add("Item2", 42, 3)
```

Source [DotNetPerls.com : VB.NET DataTable](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datatable-vbnet)