# Why is new not used when a DataTable object is created?

Tags: vb.net

I understand that everything in vb.net is a object. If that is the case, why is new keyword not used when creating a datatable object?

```
Dim dt as Datatable
dt.coloumns.add()
```

vs

```
Dim dt as Datatable = new Datatable
dt.coloumns.add()
```

Both seem to do the same things. However, in which  scenario should I use new keyword? Are therere specific objects I don't need to use the new keyword? I understand that for common things like string, integer etc you don't need to instantiate the object. Is it the same case for DataTable too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dim dt as Datatable` is merely declaration of the variable. It does not initialise it, so by default the value of `dt` is null (`Nothing` in VB I believe). Note that only declaring the value is not illegal at all, so you are perfectly within your rights to do so.

On the other hand, `Dim dt as Datatable = new Datatable` declares as well as initialises the variable. That is to say, `new` will initialise the declared variable with the appropriate value. If an class has a constructor which accepts parameters, then you can use `new` along with the constructor to create a new instance of that class and assign your chosen values to  the class properties instead of using the default values.

The difference between your examples is that `dt.Columns.add()` will throw an error in the first example, since you are trying to call a method on a null object. In the second case, you have used `new` to provide an initial value to the variable. As a result, you can access the `Columns` property of a non-null object without any issue.

Now let's come to your other point - "I understand that for common things like string, integer etc you don't need to instantiate the object. Is it the same case for DataTable too?" Things like `Integer` are primitive datatypes, and so they have default non-null values. If you don't explicitly initialise with a value, they will take the default values. e.g. `Dim x As Integer` will automatically make `x` equal to 0

For objects, the default value is null, so it will cause problems if you try to do anything with that object without assigning a non-null value to it first. There are 2 ways to assign the non-null value:

1. Use `new` to initialise it.
2. Directly assign a value which is the result of some other processing in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply shree. But, I don't need the new keyword. I don't get any errors. The code works fine. Just to amend my question- Why is new not necessary when creating an instance of a DataTable?

Comment: @SamsonBujju I'm pretty sure the first example will throw an error. Check this: http://rextester.com/ACPYTJ71222

Comment: I think you are right. What do you think about the second answer in this post though? It is done without instatntiatng the object. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239469/vb-net-creating-data-table

Comment: The second answer will have the same error. I believe it is just meant to show how to add columns and rows, but not a ready-to-run solution

Comment: I don't think I have explained my question very well. Please visit the link. If the datatable is receiving a value, the new keyword does not needs to be used. http://rextester.com/ZBE85595

Comment: That's what my second point says. What you have in your question is definitely not the same as the code in your link.

Comment: Sorry forgot to see your updated answer. Now everything is clear. Thanks a lot for the help.